# Use instance method from other class

Tags: ruby

I created a class that returns the local time of cities.

```
class GetTime
  def london
    #some code
  end

  def newyork
    #some code
  end
end

time = GetTime.new
time.london # => 2015-10-16 10:46:54
```

Let's imagine I have a shop on each city that is open 9 to 17 and I want to determine if this shop is open. I defined the class `MarketOpen`. I would like to call its method `is_open?` on an instance of `GetTime`. The method should return `true` if the time returned from `time.london` is between 9 to 17.

```
class MarketOpen
  def is_open?
    #some code
  end
end

time.london.is_open?
```

Is this achievable? Would it be a good practice? What would be the best approach to call a method from another class?

Comment: If `time.london` is an object of time (or its subclass), then `is_open?` has to be a method on time (or its subclass). Why do you have `MarketOpen`?

Comment: @lurker It makes sense to assign location to a time. In fact, time instances have an attribute called time zone.

Comment: @sawa indeed, that is true, I didn't consider the time zone scenario. But I still would not ultimately consider "hours of operation" of a market to be a method that's part of time/timezone in general.

Comment: @sawa just because I was trying to keep each class doing just one thing. one get the time, one get the info about the market open/closed. But again, this could be a bad approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not convinced that `GetTime` is a usefull model, but I will keep it unchanged in this example. Then I would change `Shop` to something like this:

```
class Shop
  attr_reader :location

  def initialize(location)
    @location = location
  end

  def open?
    # some code checking `local_time` against opening hours
  end

private

  def local_time
    time = GetTime.new
    time.send(location)
  end
end
```

The following should return your expected result:

```
shop = Shop.new('London')
shop.open?
```

**Update:** I would implement the local time calculation using [`Time#getlocal`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Time.html#method-i-getlocal):

```
class LocalTime
  attr_reader :time

  ZONES = {
    'Tokyo'    => '+09:00',
    'Berlin'   => '+01:00'
    'London'   => '+00:00',
    'New York' => '-05:00'
    # ...
  }

  def self.for(location)
    new.for(location)
  end

  def initialize
    @time = Time.now
  end

  def for(location)
    offset = ZONES.fetch(location)
    time.getlocal(offset)
  end

end
```

Using this implementation would allow to change the private `local_time` method in my answer to:

```
def local_time
  LocalTime.for(location)
end
```

Comment: thanks @spickermann do you think there is a better way to define local times?

Comment: Or4ct2, you might make `GetTime` a module and its methods module methods (`def self.london...`). Better, I think, is (for a `GetTime` module) define a constant hash with keys cities and values times zones, and then have just a single module method, used like so: `GetTime.for("Toyko")` or `GetTime.for(:toyko)`.

Comment: @spickermann there is still another problem, dst... now London is +1 but it won't be in 2 weeks

Comment: @0r4cl3 : You might want to consider using [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) or another gem instead of trying to solve dst issues yourself.